# Math notation clarification

Tags: notation, regression, machine-learning

I'm working on learning more about logistic regression and I came across an equation with some confusing notation that I've never seen before:

$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta \theta_{y'}^{(j)}} l(\theta) = \sum^N_{n=1} \left[ [y_n = y'] x_n^{(j)} - p(y' | x_n) x_n^{(j)} \right]
$$

The part that is unclear is the $[y_n = y']$. Is this just supposed to be a sort of if statement in mathematics?

Something like, "only process the following if this constraint holds true"?

Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's probably an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: ... also it is probably explained prior to this point in that document, whatever it is.

Comment: Nah, there was no explanation of that term.  Thanks @RandyE that was it! Feel free to create an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).